# PHP/mySQL---Select max value where another value exists

Tags: php, mysql

I was recently working with PHP and MYSQL on a project with a friend of mine. I seem to be coming over the same problem over and over.

I have a database setup that stores 2 values: id (auto-incremental) and user_id.

When the script is started, it writes to the database the id and the user_id. The user_id is previously assigned. Once that happens, another query occurs which looks in the table for the maximum "id" where there is a specific "user_id". this is then is written as a file name and the script is done.

The part that I am having trouble with is the part that it fetches the maximum id. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','PASSWORD') or die("Couldn't connect to database");
mysql_select_db('post', $connect) or die("Couldn't find database");
$user = $_SESSION['id'];
$post_data = $_POST['post'];

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `post`(`id`, `user`) VALUES ('','$user')")  or die("failed to connect to database");

$idquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM post) AND user='$user'") or die("failed to find max post");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($idquery) or die("failed to query max post")){
    $db_postid = $row['id'];
    }
$fc = fopen("./users/post" . $id . ".txt","r+")  or die("failed to create file");
fwrite($fc,$post_data) or die("failed to write to file");
fclose($fc) or die("failed to close file");
?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks a ton.

Comment: So you are just wanting to know what the max id is?

Comment: Why not simply use the last inserted id value: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, that you need to select MAX id at all. PHP has a function:

[mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) - Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT). I think, it's your case.

As you are inserting only 1 row, try this:

```
$db_postid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Please, don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli instead. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: you don't quote $user variable before using it in INSERT query.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Now I have to figure out why my server with 777 permissions won't let me write a file...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM post) AND ...
```

Off topic:

You should use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to make your MySQL connections instead of mysql_ functions which are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM post WHERE user_id = 123
```